# why nested class not visible to outer class

Tags: c++, nested, declaration

i was confused with a problem of nested class

```
#ifndef MINIGRAPH_H_
#define MINIGRAPH_H_
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
template <typename VEX,typename EDGE>
class MiniGraph
{
public:
    class _Node
    {
    public:
        VEX _Vex;
        EDGE _Edge;
         _Node* next;
    };
    MiniGraph() {};
    MiniGraph(int vex_num);
    void add(VEX from, VEX to, EDGE Edge);
    //void display();
private:
    std::vector<void*> _VecNode;
    _Node* NewNode(VEX vex) { _Node* ptr = new _Node;ptr->_Vex = vex;return ptr; }
    _Node* NewNode(VEX vex, EDGE edge) { _Node* ptr = new _Node;ptr->_Vex = vex;ptr->_Edge = edge;return ptr; }

};
template <typename VEX, typename EDGE>
MiniGraph<VEX, EDGE>::MiniGraph(int vex_num)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < vex_num;i++)
    {
        struct Node *ptr_tmp = new _Node;
        ptr_tmp->next = NULL;
        _VecNode.push_back(ptr_tmp);
    }
}
template <typename VEX, typename EDGE>
void MiniGraph<VEX, EDGE>::add(VEX from, VEX to, EDGE edge)
{
    int i;
     _Node* ptr_node = NULL;
    for (i = 1;i < _VecNode.size();i++)
    {
        ptr_node = (_Node*)_VecNode[i];
        if (ptr_node->_Vex == from)
            break;
    }
    if (i == _VecNode.size())
    {
        ptr_node = NewNode(from);
        _VecNode.push_back(ptr_node);
    }
    ptr_node = NewNode(from, edge);
    **ptr_node->next = (_Node*)_VecNode[i]->next;//insert node from head**
    _VecNode[i]->next = ptr_node;
}
```

when compiled with

```
#include "MiniGraph.h"
void main()
{
    MiniGraph<int, double> hh;
    hh.add(1, 2, 0.1);
    hh.add(1, 3, 0.2);
    hh.add(2, 3, 0.3);
}
```

error triggered in `ptr_node->next = (_Node*)_VecNode[i]->next;//insert node from head`
saying ->next left must point to class/struct/union/generic type;
but _Node was declared 。i was tring to substitute class by struct,but it triggered the same error.
it seems that declaration is not visible.how should i solve this problem?

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved to the implementation for any use. `_Node` is not a valid name for a user type. Nor is `_VecNode` a valid member name.

Comment: `((_Node*)_VecNode[i])->next` will fix one problem, but there are many more. Why on Earth would you use a `void*`?!

Comment: I think you are mixing some pretty bad style C-style programming with modern C++ and things are not looking well... Convert/Refactor your code to C++ and the problem will appear by itself.

Comment: Class nesting, and the permission management therein, has nothing to do with this. `_VecNode[i]->next` cannot possibly work, since `_VecNode` is a `std::vector<void*>`. As far as the compiler is concerned, there is no `next`, because `_VecNode[i]` is `void*`. What possible engineering problem is being addressed by storing `void*` should be considered, because chances are t's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @ DeiDei  aha, i had just implemented a Set template class that used std::list which do not support template parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WhozCraig mentioned in the comments above, you have a vector of `void*`, not a vector of `Node*`. Therefore there is no member called `next`. You can type_cast the `void*` to a `Node*` to "fix" the problem, but you would be in for a surprise.

The problem start from your `main` function.

```
int main()
{
    MiniGraph<int, double> hh;
```

This code will call the default constructor of the `MiniGraph` class. This means that no `Nodes` will be created and your vector of `Node*` will be empty (i.e. `std::vector<Node*>::size = 0`.

Then you call the `add` function:

```
hh.add(1, 2, 0.1);
```

Inside the `add` function the following happens:

```
void add(VEX from_, VEX to_, EDGE edge_)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;

    for (i=1; i<node_ptrs.size(); i++)
    {
        if (node_ptrs[i]->vex == from_)
            break;
    }
```

After the first call to `add()`, the vector `size = 0`, but `i = 1`. That's because you initialize `i=1` inside the for-loop.

Then you check if `i == vector::size`.

```
    Node *tmp = nullptr;
    if (i == node_ptrs.size())
    {
        tmp = NewNode(from_);
        node_ptrs.push_back(tmp);
    }
```

The if-statement above will never be executed, because `i = 1` and `vector::size = 0`.

Finally, you do the following:

```
    tmp = NewNode(from_, edge_);
    tmp->next = node_ptrs[i]->next; // this fails because your vector size is 0!
    node_ptrs[i]->next = tmp;
```

The first line works. `tmp` is a `Node*` which points to a newly created `Node`. ok. Then the program fails with a segmentaion fault because `tmp->next` is trying to shallow copy the pointer in the `i` element of the vector. Remember now that `i = 1` and the vector is still empty, i.e. `vector::size = 0`. There is no `node_ptrs[1]` element to copy from. And that's why it crashes.

Example of the code above: https://rextester.com/DTODK86272

There are more problems to consider in your original code... For example:

- if only one pointer is meant to point at a certain `Node`, then use a `unique_ptr`. You can still have other pointer reading from a `unique_ptr`, but they won't be able to do anything else.
- write constructors that initialize your pointers to `nullptr` and call a zero initialization on the `vex` and `edge` members.
- Avoid using `int` as array indices. What if someone decides to use a negative number as a function argument?
- In your implementation you must check if the vector is empty before you start doing anything else. What should happen if the vector is empty?